# Key Error Pandas pd.isnull

Tags: python, pandas, isnull

Part of my code looks like this:

```
#generate exceptions CSV where ascomb['Discipline']=='""'

#ascombnb: THESE ARE THE MERGED, NON-BLANK ASSESSMENTS AND STUDENTS RECORDS
ascombnoa = ascomb[pd.isnull(ascomb['Discipline'])]
ascombnoa.to_csv(str(out_folder)+'\Exceptions\Students_Without_Assessments'+str(st)+'.csv', sep=',')
ascombnos = ascomb[pd.isnull(ascomb['Grade'])]
ascombnos.to_csv(str(out_folder)+'\Exceptions\Assessments_Without_Students'+str(st)+'.csv', sep=',')
```

I have been using this code for months and it never produced this key error (it's associated with 'Discipline'.

Comment: Please show the exact error you got + show the output of `ascomb.info()`. This typically means there is no column 'Discipline'

Comment: Also you should be able to call `isnull` on the series itself, there is no need to use the top-level `pd.isnull` so `ascomb[ascomb['Discipline'].isnull()]` should still work